# Kernel panic - Unable to mount root fs on uknown-block(0,0). Same error when selecting older kernel or trying a liveUSB

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount

My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server wasn't responding so I've hooked it up to a mouse/keyboard/monitor. I am running it on an Intel NUC (NUC7i3DNHE).

It's showing the above kernel panic message. I have had this before when an update has failed to install, and remember following instructions to fix it by booting an older kernel version. I'm not sure if it was an auto-update that triggered the error this time but it seems to have been offline since yesterday.

One difference to the other posts I found is that I see multiple messages like `check: Corrupted low memory at 00000004ac315r1ea29ab (fee0 phys) = 000` and `Memory corruption detected in low memory`, just before the kernel panic messages.

Unfortunately I am getting the same `unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)` error with any of the 4 boot options I have (2 kernel versions, 2 recovery versions) and also if I try to boot from a Live USB with Ubuntu on it. Do I need to try a different distro?

This means I've got no access to a terminal so I have no idea how to get around the problem. I can't even re-install because it won't let me get to a point where I can boot any OS. What do I do now?

Comment: It seems you have a defective or corrupt drive and/or RAM issues.

Comment: It was working fine until Ubuntu did an auto-update. I've since tried to reinstall but the only things I can get to actually boot are debian/unix based liveUSBs. I've been able to successfully install Debian but it's giving me the same errors when booting. I've even tried a windows 10 USB (which I have used recently on another machine - works great) but that just shows a blue screen and shuts the PC down. I will order a new SSD for the NUC and try that I guess.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It was faulty RAM. Forgot to update this. Good call. Thanks